# Update table with info from a different table with an increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join, common-table-expression

I want to update table 2 with any of the the ID's from table 1 where parentId = parentId

But only for the amount that I have in table 1

So if I have in table 1 5 records for parentId 1 then only update table2 5 records where parentId = 1

Table 1:

```
id          NAME                                               ParentId
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1           Name1                                              1
2           Name2                                              1
3           Name3                                              1
4           Name4                                              1
5           Name5                                              1
```

Table 2:

```
Id          name                                               Table1Id    ParentId
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
7           Name7                                              NULL        1
8           Name8                                              NULL        1
9           Name9                                              NULL        1
10          Name10                                             NULL        1
11          Name11                                             NULL        1
12          Name12                                             NULL        1
13          Name13                                             NULL        1
14          Name14                                             NULL        1
```

What I need

```
Id          name                                               Table1Id    ParentId
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
7           Name7                                              1           1
8           Name8                                              2           1
9           Name9                                              3           1
10          Name10                                             4           1
11          Name11                                             5           1
12          Name12                                             NULL        1
13          Name13                                             NULL        1
14          Name14                                             NULL        1
```

I tried getting a rownum for each and join on that but I got error **Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You need to generate a key for joining them.  Use `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by parentid order by id) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     )
update toupdate
    set Table1Id = t1.id
    from toupdate join
         (select t1.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by parentid order by id) as seqnum
          from table1 t1
         ) t1
         on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum and t1.parentid = t2.parentid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate the rows in both table, then update. I like to do this kind of tasks with updateable CTEs, which in SQL Server are surprisingly flexible:

```
with cte as (
    select t2.table1id, t1.id
    from (
        select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by parentid order by id) rn
        from table1 t1
    ) t1
    inner join (
        select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by parentid order by id) rn
        from table2 t2
    ) t2 on t2.parentid = t1.parentid and t2.rn = t1.rn
)
update cte set table1id = id
```

The upside of this approach is that you don't need to reopen the target table: each table is scanned just once, then the update occurs.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04cd3b3411b601b36e0d14bb6b06a2a0)**:

```
Id | name   | Table1Id | ParentId
-: | :----- | -------: | -------:
 7 | Name7  |        1 |        1
 8 | Name8  |        2 |        1
 9 | Name9  |        3 |        1
10 | Name10 |        4 |        1
11 | Name11 |        5 |        1
12 | Name12 |     null |        1
13 | Name13 |     null |        1
14 | Name14 |     null |        1
```